# Bixby Developer Studio sign up fails since captcha crashes

Tags: samsung-mobile, bixby

Bixby Developer Studio Developers sign up fails since captcha crashes.
Any idea on how to sign up anyway ?

Any idea, Bixby Developer Studio: AI aided programming > dynamic program generation
stays for what by examples ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Especially Capcha is not a problem when sign up to Bixby Developer Studio. However, due to this issue, we have decided to remove Capcha from Samsung Account login for the time being. If you continue to have problems, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I am a member of the Bixby Developer Support team and will help you with the sign-up process. Due to the specific nature of this issue, it is better to handle this as a Support ticket rather than a StackOverflow question.

Please raise a ticket by sending an email to support@bixbydevelopers.com and include a screenshot of the error and the approximate time when this issue occurred. Once we receive this information, we will work with our internal teams to resolve this issue and help you sign-up.